# MVC - display loader while clicks on the link from default layer

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

The Webapplication using a default layer(_Layout.cshtml) along with two views view1 & view2. Default layer has two links (Link1, link2). Each links has separate controller and it will take a while to process the data and display the view. Until then I need to show the loader. I have separate views for each controller. However the loader start displaying when the view is switches.

Im using below script in the default html ie (_Layout.cshtml).

```
    <script>
        var myVar;

        function myFunction() {
            myVar = setTimeout(showPage, 200);
        }

        function showPage() {
            document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";

        }
        document.addEventListener('readystatechange', e => {
            if (document.readyState !== "complete ") {
                console.log("111 :" + document.readyState)
                myFunction();
            } else {
                console.log("222 :" + document.readyState)
                document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
            }
        });


    </script>
```

loader CSS is below

```
    #loader {
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      z-index: 1;
      width: 120px;
      height: 120px;
      margin: -76px 0 0 -76px;
      border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
      -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
      animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    }

    @@-webkit-keyframes spin {
      0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
      100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
    }

    @@keyframes spin {
      0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
      100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
    }

    /* Add animation to "page content" */
    .animate-bottom {
      position: relative;
      -webkit-animation-name: animatebottom;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
      animation-name: animatebottom;
      animation-duration: 1s
    }

    @@-webkit-keyframes animatebottom {
      from { bottom:-100px; opacity:0 }
      to { bottom:0px; opacity:1 }
    }

    @@keyframes animatebottom {
      from{ bottom:-100px; opacity:0 }
      to{ bottom:0; opacity:1 }
    }
```

But loader shows only when views are loading. When the controller executes I want to show the loader.

Any help would be highly appreciated.